# What is the difference between G41 and G42?

Tags: cnc

I am studying Cnc programming and I got stuck on the difference between G41 and G42. The lecturer didnt explain it clearly so Im looking for somebody who can give me a clearer explaination of the difference. I know they are both cutter compensation, but how do I know when to use G41 and when to use G42?

Comment: Also, you are asking a *very* specific question, don't be surprised if it takes more than 2 minutes for an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its actually quite simple to determine the difference between G41 and G42. But if you get it wrong, It could be a really costly mistake. G41 compensates your cutter to the left, and G42 compensates your cutter to the right.

You can read more about it here:
[Cutter compensation G40 G41 G42](http://cnc-programming-by-gord.blogspot.com/2012/07/cutter-compensation-g40-g41-g42.html)

Comment: just that? is that the only difference?

Comment: Yep thats all. But make sure ur using the right code, else you are gonna havea major problem.

Answer (score 0):

I explain you in simple way G41 code is use for move cnc control tool left of the countering direction. G42 code is opposite than the G41. It can use for move cnc control tool right of the countering direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've used G42 & G41 in wire edm work.use G42 as a work comp, usually.008“wire comp (meaning it's.008" from centerline of cutting path), to skim ID keyways on size. G41 is used for OD keyways and splines. So here's a real world example for the coding application.